# Angular Flex Layout Performance with dynamic grid data

Tags: flexbox, material-design, angular-flex-layout, angular-material-5

I am loving this **flex Layout with material 2** but at the same time i am worried about the performance.
I googled and found that, this flex layout has some performance issue when it comes to table or large list.
One i found here :
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Performance-Considerations

In my project i am binding grid using *ngFor with only 20 data on my small cards and it takes around 1 sec to load while my other pages which don't have table data, they load in milliseconds.

For my project ,i have already created most of the layout with flex.
And now this performance concern for some of other employees in my organization !!!!!
I am using Anguar Material 2 with flex layout.
Can anybody suggest me the best way ???

Another link which i refered : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-jmob2p   
Shall i continue using this flex layout or shall i go back to css grid system
?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: a one second load time isn't completely unexpected. Some apps (Google news feed and Luminosity) that I think are well done take over a second to load lists/data.